# Get the previous array from a 2d array with given array passed as an argument in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, arguments

It was hard to create a title, but I'll show you:

I'm given a 2d array `arr[10][10]`

In a function, a 1d array of `arr` of size, let's say `5`, is passed as an argument:

```
int func(arr[5]);
```

What I want is: without knowing the index of the array used as the argument (in this case index 5), I want to get the array from `arr` with (index = indexgiven - 1) of given array (the previous).

So in this case, I would want:

```
int func(arr[5]){
    _array = arr[4];
}
```

**NOTE:** I CANNOT change this function's signature. My job is to create code inside the function. Then this function will be called.

Comment: Can you show these functions are declared, and are you allowed to change their signature?

Comment: Why you just don't pass only the index ?

Comment: Your first mistake is thinking that you can pass an array to a function in C++. It's all done with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you forget the idea that you are passing arrays you can do that

```
void func(int (*row)[10])
{
    int (*previous_row)[10] = row - 1;
    int (*next_row)[10] = row + 1;
    ...
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10][10];
    func(arr + 5);
}
```

But I think I prefer Adrien's idea, just pass the index.